# MVC Testing using a mocking framework (Moq)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, moq

I'm using Moq to help in testing my ASP.NET MVC2 application.

Problem:   ArgumentException was unhandled by user code.  Unable to obtain public key for StrongNameKeyPair

This code has been adapted from Scott Hanselman's NerdDinner1.

```
HomeController CreateHomeControllerAs(string userName)
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns(userName); // fails here
        mock.SetupGet(p => p.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

        var controller = new HomeController();
        controller.ControllerContext = mock.Object;

        return controller;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void should_be_able_to_get_to_index_page_logged_in()
    {
        HomeController controller = CreateHomeControllerAs("dave");
    }
```

Using Moq referenced... VS2010 under WinXP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. I've just tested it and it worked fine. The problem is with the `Moq` assembly. You need to grant specific permissions to the `C:\Documents and Settings\AllUsers\ApplicationData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` folder. Checkout [this discussion](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/RhinoMocks/browse_thread/thread/26df68ff01567509/5ddebf407228edc4).

Also right click on the `Moq.dll` in Windows Explorer and in the properties make sure that it is not locked. When you download some DLL from the internet Windows automatically applies restricted permissions to it.

Comment: Awesome.. I wrote a blog post on this too http://www.programgood.net/2010/07/05/ArgumentExceptionWasUnhandledByUserCodeUnableToObtainPublicKeyForStrongNameKeyPair.aspx