# How to fix the StrongNameKeyPair error in .Net for using Moq?

Tags: .net, moq

As far as I can see, it is necessary to have access to write in the machine key store. So how do I assign this permission to a user? I need to ask support people to grant a user the necessary permissions to run Moq, but I don't know what exactly to ask for.

***UPDATE***: As Tim requested below, I'm updating with some information that might be useful to the problem understanding, as follows:

Apparently, Moq relies on Castle to build mock objects, and the Castle framework needs to write to machine key store. When I try to run the tests, the testing framework return the error "Unable to obtain public key for StrongNameKeyPair".

When I went to support guys, they temporarily gave me administrative privileges, and everything ran as expected. Even after they removed the admin permissions, I was able to execute my tests.

My conclusion of this was that I need some permission to write on this machine key store. What I need to know is where exactly I need to have writing permissions, so I could ask support for a specific writing permission instead of admin permissions, for the other development environments, what would be denied for sure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I was able to find the exact directory I need to have write permission in order to execute Moq (in fact, it's a Castle requirement). The user must have acces to the following folder:

C:\Documents and Settings\AllUsers\ApplicationData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

(Assuming "C" is your system folder)

With this permission, the user running a mocking project with Moq won't need admministrative privileges in the local machine. Here is a reference:

[MVC Testing using a mocking framework (Moq)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177654/mvc-testing-using-a-mocking-framwork-moq)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was having a problem with the Orchard CMS 1.6.
It worked. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

I've never needed to install any keys to run Moq, neither locally on my workstation nor on our build server. I think you might need to put a bit more work into your question. Are you getting some sort of error? Perhaps if you posted the message you might get a better response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Tim. I'll update the question with some additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to MjLogan Answer; In Windows 10, the location is C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys
In Properties of 'MachineKeys' folder Set Permission of Users to Full Control.